# dd sticking and not working

Tags: terminal, usb, unix, diskutil

So, I used:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/****/Downloads/kali-linux-2019-2-amd64-iso.dmg of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

to flash a bootable usb drive, but it never started copying... So now I can't access/mount/unmount the drive.

What I noticed trying to check it out was, that dd is not working at all...
dd sticks the same way, no matter what command (even just trying to get the list of commands) I try.

Any ideas on what could be wrong and/or how to fix the drive?

Comment: Have you unmounted disk2?

Comment: This site works better with one question per post, so what is your main question here? Getting `dd` to work or fixing the drive? Assuming the second, can you please add some details showing the state of the disk (DiskUtility screenshot, error message you get when mounting/unmounting in Terminal etc)?

Comment: You should copy `kali-linux-2019-2-amd64.iso` not `kali-linux-2019-2-amd64-iso.dmg` and expect it to take up to half an hour according to [their documentation](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install).  Reboot and try again...